# Change label from input javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to change the label text once the user has changed the input field text.

This is what I have so far:

script function:

```
 function ModuleName() {
        var text = document.getElementById('txtModCode').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('lblModCode').innerHTML = text;

    }
```

fields and label

```
<input type="text" name="txtModCode" id="txtModCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Module Code Here" onchange="ModuleName()" />
<label id="lblModCode"></label>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: So, what is wrong with what you have above?

Comment: inputs have value, not innerHTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.value` in `document.getElementById('txtModCode').value;`, not `.innerHTML`

```js
function ModuleName() {
  var text = document.getElementById('txtModCode').value;
  document.getElementById('lblModCode').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txtModCode" id="txtModCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Module Code Here" onchange="ModuleName()" />
<label id="lblModCode"></label>
```

---

And by utilizing *this* in `onchange="ModuleName(this)"` you can pass a direct reference to the `input` and avoid the extra `getElementById`

```js
function ModuleName(el) {
  document.getElementById('lblModCode').innerHTML = el.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txtModCode" id="txtModCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Module Code Here" onchange="ModuleName(this)" />
<label id="lblModCode"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a textbox that triggers a function when the contained text is changed use this:

```
 <body>
      <span id="thing2">you have not changed the textbox</span>
      <input type="text" id="thing" onchange="myFunction()">
 </body>
 <script>
      function myFunction(){
           document.getElementById("thing2").innerText = "you have changed the textbox"
      }
 </script>
```

This changes the contents of the  element

Comment: This changes the label whenever you change the textbox, this does not make the label copy the textbox.